# Regular Expression, match url segments in specific order?

Tags: php, regex

I would like to match url pattern that has optional segments.

I have URL-s like this:

```
subdomain.domain.com/page/pageurl/pagename/123/
subdomain.domain.com/page/pageurl/pagename/
subdomain.domain.com/page/pageurl/
subdomain.domain.com/page/
```

Now I have a regex that matches all those situations:

```
^([a-z]+)\.domain\.com\/page(\/[a-z]+)?(\/[a-z]+)?(\/[0-9]+)?\/?$
```

But this regexs fails if you go to this URL:

```
subdomain.domain.com/page/123/
```

It matches this url too, and I dont want that to happen beacuse first segment should be [a-z]+ and nothing else. Now I do understand why is this happening, but I cant figure out the right regexs to suite my needs.
I need a regexs that would match those URL-s but in order, so if first segment after page is number, it should not match...

How would I do that? Im going crazy right now :S

Rubural example: [LINK](http://rubular.com/r/jyNIgl08Un)

Thanks!

Comment: No, this is in PHP, Im using preg_match() to match URL-s.

Comment: just remove the question mark behind the capturing group of the first 'segment', `(\/[a-z]+)? becomes (\/[a-z]+)

Comment: That would prevent his fourth pattern from matching

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can make the capturing group of the first 'segment' mandatory and all of the segments optional like so:
`^([a-z]+)\.domain\.com\/page(?:(\/[a-z]+)(\/[a-z]+)?(\/[0-9]+)?)?\/?$`

Another thing that might be useful is to allow any valid subdomain, the pattern would look like this:

`^([\w.-]+)+\.domain\.com\/page(?:(\/[a-z]+)(\/[a-z]+)?(\/[0-9]+)?)?\/?$`

Edit: Fixed pattern, as Umbrella pointed out (thanks) my prevous pattern would not match your last example string, oops

Answer (score 4):

I think what you need is a look-behind

```
^([a-z]+)\.domain\.com\/page(\/[a-z]+)?(\/[a-z]+)?((?<!\/page)\/[0-9]+)?\/?$
```

What the `(?<!\/page)` should do is assert that '/page' does not immediately precede the numbers.

**EDIT**

I tested it like this:

```
$re = '/^([a-z]+)\.domain\.com\/page(\/[a-z]+)?(\/[a-z]+)?((?<!\/page)\/[0-9]+)?\/?$/';
foreach(array(
        'subdomain.domain.com/page/pageurl/pagename/123/',
        'subdomain.domain.com/page/pageurl/pagename/',
        'subdomain.domain.com/page/pageurl/',
        'subdomain.domain.com/page/',
        'subdomain.domain.com/page/123/',
        ) as $url
) {
    $matches = array();
    preg_match($re,$url,$matches);
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

and got matches for the first four, and not the last.

Comment: Thanks Umbrella, but I didnt needed look-behind. Your example works, but for the problem "im" solving other answer better suites me.
Anyway thanks alot!! :) You helped me learn some new tricks with regexs :)